# Write html tag with Markdown?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, markdown, tumblr

In tumblr, markdown is supported. 
I try to add a syntax high lighter([highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/)) in my tumblr, but got some problem.

highlight.js need adding a *class* attribute in HTML code tag.

I try to write a article like this in my tumblr :

```
<pre class="test">
    <code class="html">
        function A(){ return "hello world"; }
    </code>
</pre>
```

The result in real page:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        function A(){ return "hello world"; }
    </code>
</pre>
```

The *class* attribute is gone......
Is there possible adding a HTML attribute in Markdown?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), you could do this (I am currently doing this):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint');
    prettyPrint();
});
```

Basically, you load all the files:

```
prettify.css
sunburst.css // optional styles
prettify.js
```

Add the code snippet above, and call `prettyPrint` `onLoad`: `onload="prettyPrint()"`.

The code snippet above should go before all the files. It finds all `pre` elements, and appends the `prettyprint` class to it so that the script knows to style it.

---

If, however, you wanted to use your current syntax highlighter, you could do something like this (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre').addClass('test');
    $('code').addClass('html');
    // code to intialize highlight.js
});
```

Comment: If `onload="prettyPrint()"` is already added in the `<body>`, `prettyPrint()` is not required in the argument of `ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried, it was not difficult.

http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/ describes in the first code snippet what you need to plug into the html of your tumblr page to make it work. **The code snippet will not load with highlighting in the preview mode.**

To be able to use the highlighter you need to be able to link the stylesheet and the javascript. If you don't have hosting then the guys of highlight.js offer a hosted solution for free.

Add these 3 lines inside your `<head>...</head>` tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.2/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.2/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

All I added to my code post on the tumblr was

```
<pre><code class="language-python">
...your code here...
</code></pre>
```